# Crosswalk CUSTOM append to user agent

Tags: mobile, crosswalk

My app requires custom user agent addition like "***; myAppUA".

For example, in webview I can do it:

```
    String userAgent = settings.getUserAgentString();
    userAgent += "; myAppUA";
    settings.setUserAgentString(userAgent);
```

But I cannot find how to do it in Crosswalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found patch here:
https://github.com/Reconers/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview/commit/f2b5d44b66a50b8fa4eeea9810c20cc29c601147

Now you can add in config.xml in app:

```
    <preference name="AppendUserAgent" value="myAppUA" />
```